# Fluorine and fossils

Tags: isotope, radioactivity

> They are now assisted by chemists who are able to fix dates through the analysis of pollen, radioactive carbon, and **fluorine found in connection with fossils..**

Here the text is talking about basic paleontology.

Could anyone teach me in a simple way how fluorine is connected with fossils findings?

(This is originally about English test (TOEFL), but the subject in question does not in my opinion belong to ELL)

Comment: Apparently, fossils absorb fluorine https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorine_absorption_dating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the literature, it has been reported that fluorine ions replace hydroxyl ions in osseous tissue (bone) so by making a measurement of the flourine content of bone it is possible to estimate the age of the bones.

One early paper on the subject is Cook, S. F.; Ezra-cohn, H. C. An Evaluation of the Fluorine Dating Method. *Southwestern Journal of Anthropology* **1959,** *15* (3), 276–290. [DOI: 10.1086/soutjanth.15.3.3628977](https://doi.org/10.1086/soutjanth.15.3.3628977).

One method would be to use neutron activation anaylsis on bones to measure the flourine-19, using the n,gamma reaction. This method does have a problem as sodium-23 can form flourine-20 by a n,alpha reaction. As a result a correction will have to be made for the sodium content of the bones.

This is discussed in Cheng, T. P.; Anderson, H. D.; Mills, D. S.; Spate, V. L.; Baskett, C. K.; Morris, J. S. Determination of the fluoride distribution in rabbit bone using instrumental neutron activation analysis. *J. Radioanal. Nucl. Chem.* **1997,** *217* (2), 171–174. [DOI: 10.1007/BF02034437](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02034437).